# how do i type a word in a text box whose xpath is changing using selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

Hi i am testing a travel domain site and there on booking details page i am getting the different xpath of same edit box based on my search if searched for 3 adults and 2 child the xpath of adult two is same as child 1 if i search for 1 adult 1 child so my script get failed want some suggestion ??? i have tried different target drop down options also in selenium but not working :( my script is in case one if i search for 3 adult 2 child i get second adult xpath as below

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=cphSiteContentView_cphContentPanel_ucBookingSummary_ucShoppingCart_rptProductList_ctl00_0_ucTravellersContactDetails_0_rptRoomsDetails_0_rptAdultDetails_2_txtLastName_4</td>
    <td>thfh</td>
</tr>
```

And if search for 1 adult and 1 child i got the same xpath

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=cphSiteContentView_cphContentPanel_ucBookingSummary_ucShoppingCart_rptProductList_ctl00_0_ucTravellersContactDetails_0_rptRoomsDetails_0_rptAdultDetails_2_txtLastName_4</td>
    <td>thfh</td>
</tr>
```

want some suggestion how to identify ?

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like the following for the target:

xpath=//*[contains(@id,'cphSiteContentView_cphContentPanel_ucBookingSummary_ucShoppingCart_rptProductList_ctl00')]

the trick is to search for a part of the id if it is dynamic. Please bear in mind that you need make the id unique enough that you wont return 2 or more elements other wise IDE will simply pick the first it comes across

you can edit anything inside the quote marks to make the xpath unique enough to only pick the id you want.